# Use css to hide input type=text

Tags: css

```
<form action="http://****.com/message/?fepaction=checkmessage" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    To: <br><input type="text" name="message_to" placeholder="Username of recipient" autocomplete="off" value=""><br>Subject:<br>
    <input type="text" name="message_title" placeholder="Subject" maxlength="65" value=""><br>Message:<br><div id="wp-message_content-wrap" class="wp-core-ui wp-editor-wrap tmce-active">
    .....    

</form>
```

I want to hide

```
To: <br><input type="text" name="message_to" placeholder="Username of recipient" autocomplete="off" value="">
```

using css

My current css is

```
#fep-content input[type=text] {
    width: 45%;
    min-width: 250px;
}
```

If I add

```
input[type="text"] {
    display: none;
}
```

then both 2 fields are hide.
I just want to hide 1 field and the word "To"

How to do that?

Comment: Hiding the input field is possible but hiding "To" alone would be tough because it is not wrapped inside another element. Font size 0px trick could be used on the form but it would hide "Subject" and "Message" also.

Comment: Ok, I will remove "To" in html file. How is to hide the field?

Comment: It could be done with the attribute selector and one of the existing answers already describe it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can select input by name using [`Attribute selector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

```css
input[name="message_to"] {
  display: none;  
}
```

```html
<form action="http://****.com/message/?fepaction=checkmessage" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    To: <br><input type="text" name="message_to" placeholder="Username of recipient" autocomplete="off" value=""><br>Subject:<br>
    <input type="text" name="message_title" placeholder="Subject" maxlength="65" value=""><br>Message:<br><div id="wp-message_content-wrap" class="wp-core-ui wp-editor-wrap tmce-active"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: @Jon [Ok, I will remove "To" in html file. How is to hide the field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34454238/use-css-to-hide-input-type-text#comment56650076_34454238)

Answer (score 1):

```
 <form action="http://****.com/message/?fepaction=checkmessage" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div id="something">
        To: <br><input type="text" name="message_to" placeholder="Username of recipient" autocomplete="off" value=""></div><br>Subject:<br>
        <input type="text" name="message_title" placeholder="Subject" maxlength="65" value=""><br>Message:<br><div id="wp-message_content-wrap" class="wp-core-ui wp-editor-wrap tmce-active">
        .....    

    </form>
```

add

```
#something {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot ways that you can hide the first input(`name=message_to`). For hiding the `To` you can use `:first-line` and then give `width` and `overflow:hidden` to `form` without wrapping `To` by an element.

```css
/* input[name="message_to"] */
/* input:first-child */
/* input:nth-child(1) */
/* input:nth-of-type(1) */
input:first-of-type,
br:first-of-type{
  display: none;
}
form {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
form:first-line {
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
}
```

```html
<form action="http://****.com/message/?fepaction=checkmessage" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  To:
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="message_to" placeholder="Username of recipient" autocomplete="off" value="">
  <br>Subject:
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="message_title" placeholder="Subject" maxlength="65" value="">
  <br>Message:
  <br>
  <div id="wp-message_content-wrap" class="wp-core-ui wp-editor-wrap tmce-active"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: cool! is there any css to remove white space above the "Subject"?

Comment: Yes, you can. It is because of `<br>`. You can remove it or give `display:none`. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also hide like this:

```
input:nth-child(2) {
display: none;
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp